# ImageMagick (display Q16) as selection option to alter image gone in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, imagemagick

In Ubuntu 16.04 I was able to select ImageMagick (display Q16) as option when I right click on an image to manipulate the image... in a fresh 18.04 its gone. How can I get it back as select option and use ImageMagick (display Q16) in 18.04?

[image: context menu for image]